# Activator.GetObject for creating a proxy to a serverobject with specific culture

Tags: c#, remoting, activator

We are using the Activator.GetObject method to create a proxy that our client side uses. 
The problem is that all calls on this proxy is made with the default cultureInfo on the computer. In our case "sv-SE". We have a section on the app.config that states what culture to use. This works fine on the client side.

We whant to be able to specify another culture to be used on all proxy-calls. 
Like Activator.Getobject(....., new CultureInfo("en-EN")).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Best regards
Linus